# Qt - Get QPushButton icon name

Tags: c++, qt, icons, qpushbutton

I have a two state QPushButton. I want to associate an icon to each state.

It is like Play|Pause buttons in music players.

To do so, I would like to get the current icon name in order to know what the next icon to set will be.

I could subclass QPushButton but is it worth it?

Comment: why not set the icon according to push state ? using `QPushButton::ischecked()`

Comment: I tried: `myButton->setStyleSheet(":checked {image: url(:/img/pause.png);}");` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use QPushButton::icon() and QIcon::name() to get the icon name.

Comment: This method doesn't exist for [QIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html).

Comment: It does, in both Qt 4.8 and 5.0:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qicon.html

Comment: Nevermind, the function does not work, Qt messed it up

Answer (score 7):

Instead of setting an icon based on the `QPushButton`'s state, set one `QIcon` that has two states, Qt will select the correct icon if you use it with a checkable `QPushButton`.

```
QIcon icon = QIcon();
// 'Off' state corresponds to unchecked state of QPushButton
icon.addPixmap( QPixmap( ":/img/play.png" ), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off );
// 'On' state corresponds to checked state of QPushButton
icon.addPixmap( QPixmap( ":/img/pause.png" ), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::On );
QPushButton * button = new QPushButton();
button->setIcon( icon );
button->setCheckable( true );
```