# QT Style QPushButton differently whether has Icon or not?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

Is it possible to style QPushButtons separately from a qss stylesheet whether it has an icon applied or not?
Something like:

```
QPushButton[hasIcon="true"] {
    background-color: green;
}
QPushButton[hasIcon="false"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could check the icon name ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062776/qt-get-qpushbutton-icon-name

Comment: I can but I want it to be generic, if it has any icon style it with A and if it has no icon style it with B. Is it possible or always I would have to refer to its name? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could check if the name is empty which would be your hasIcon==false ?

Comment: How can I do that on a stylesheet? I tried what I pasted in the original question and didn't work...